# Variation of action with Killing vectors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, vector-fields

Let $u^m\rightarrow u^m+\frac{d}{d\tau}k^m$.

> How does $S=m\int d\tau\sqrt{-g_{mn}u^mu^n}$ change to first order under this transformation if $k$ is a Killing vector?

My attempt:
Using $\frac{d}{d\tau}k^m=(\nabla_lk^m)u^l$, I thought
\begin{align}
S'&=m\int d\tau\sqrt{-g_{mn}(u^m+\frac{d}{d\tau}k^m)(u^n+\frac{d}{d\tau}k^n)}\\
&=m\int d\tau\sqrt{-g_{mn}(u^mu^n+(\nabla_lk^m)u^lu^n+(\nabla_lk^n)u^lu^m)}
\end{align}
Then I think I can use $\nabla_{(l}k_{m)}=0$ to show that $S'=S$. But how? What is the next step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**(I hope)

So what I think you do is the following: begin by multiplying the metric tensor in to the final two terms to get the following expression (obviously this is under a square root and there is another term. However, I've omitted for clarity)

$$ \left( \nabla_l g_{mn}k^m \right)u^lu^n+\left(\nabla_l g_{mn}k^n \right)u^lu^m.$$

Next, I would contract the metric tensor with the  Killing vector to get

$$ \left( \nabla_l k_n \right)u^lu^n+\left(\nabla_l k_m \right)u^lu^m.$$

Finally, changing the $l$ index in both expressions we can then use Killing's equation

$$ \nabla_\mu k_\nu + \nabla_\nu k_\mu \equiv 0,$$

and from there you should be able to show $S=S'$.

Comment: What do you mean by "similar operation on the $l$ index"?

Comment: So what I mean is change the $l$ index as its repeated. I've slightly updated the Phrasing in the answer.